# How to create a function based on another dataframe column being True?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, boolean

I have a dataframe shown below:

```
     Name   X    Y
0    A      False True
1    B      True  True
2    C      True  False
```

I want to create a function for example:

```
example_function("A") = "A is in Y"
example_function("B") = "B is in X and Y"
example_function("C") = "C is in X"
```

This is my code currently (incorrect and doesn't look very efficient):

```
def example_function(name):
    for name in df['Name']:
        if df['X'][name] == True and df['Y'][name] == False:
            print(str(name) + "is in X")
        elif df['X'][name] == False and df['Y'][name] == True:
            print(str(name) + "is in Y")
        else:
            print(str(name) + "is in X and Y")
```

I eventually want to add more Boolean columns so it needs to be scalable. How can I do this? Would it be better to create a dictionary, rather than a dataframe?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the output supposed to look like?

Comment: @timgeb I have edited it, an example of the output is "A is in Y"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want a function you could do:

```
def example_function(label):
    s = df.set_index('Name').loc[label]
    l = s[s].index.to_list()
    return f'{label} is in {" and ".join(l)}'

example_function('A')
'A is in Y'

example_function('B')
'B is in X and Y'
```

You can also compute all the solutions as dictionary:

```
s = (df.set_index('Name').replace({False: pd.NA}).stack()
       .reset_index(level=0)['Name']
     )
out = s.index.groupby(s)
```

output:

```
{'A': ['Y'], 'B': ['X', 'Y'], 'C': ['X']}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly. However, if I add more columns, how do I make it say "A is in W, X, Y and Z", instead of "A is in W and X and Y and Z".

Comment: You need to test the length of the list and handle differently the last element and the rest. There might even be libraries that do that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can stay with a DataFrame, the same output can be obtained with a function like this:

```
def func (name, df):
    # some checks to verify that the name is actually in the df
    occurrences_name = np.sum(df['Name'] == name)
    if occurrences_name == 0: 
        raise ValueError('Name not found')
    elif occurrences_name > 1:
        raise ValueError('More than one name found')

    # get the index corresponding to the name you're looking for
    # and select the corresponding row
    index = df[df['Name'] == name].index[0]
    row = df.drop(['Name'], axis=1).iloc[index]
    outstring = '{} is in '.format(name)
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if row[i] == True:
            if i != 0: outstring += ', '
            outstring += '{}'.format(row.index[i])
    return outstring
```

of course you can adapt this to the specific shape of your df, I'm assuming that the column containing names is actually 'Name'.

Comment: Thanks, this works but there is a small problem. If a name is False for X but True for Y, the output is "A is in , Y". Otherwise it is good.